# How to convert c++ Variant to JSON?

Tags: c++, windows, json, variant

How can I convert Variant to Java script object notation in (windows) c++?

I have a piece of hardware that returns a Variant which can contain an array(float), string or boolean data. All of variant contents should be easily converted to JSON, but is there a JSON library that does this out-of-the-box for variant? Or... Is there a JSON library (in c++) that eats almost anything and returns proper JSON.

Currently my JSON converter (sources that I downloaded from a random site) don't understand toJson(&variant).

What I am looking for is (pseudocode):

```
switch (variant.type):
    type1:
        return json.dump(variant.value)
    default:
        return json(stringify(variant.value))
```

The main point here is to get a tested and working solution with minimal effort.

**edit** By variant I mean Windows' VARIANT: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627(VS.80).aspx

br,

Juha

Comment: Are you asking about Windows' `VARIANT` or `boost::variant<>`?

Comment: Windows' variant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write this conversion manually. I'm not awarer of anything that could translate VARIANT to json or jsoncpp Value class. So just create switch that check `VARTYPE vt;` element of VARIANT and base on that convert it to for example jsoncpp Value. Probably you don't need to convert every type of VARIANT types so start with some basic ones (VT_I4, VT_UI4, VT_BSTR, VT_BOOL) and later if needed write missing types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/)? I've had some luck with it in the past.

You could use its [FastWriter class](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_fast_writer.html) to output a JSON string directly from a variant value.

Comment: hmm, I have some trouble in installing jsoncpp to win 7, 64 bit, visual studio 2010... Just by reading the instructions and source code, I get the feeling that I have to convert the input first to jsoncpp "value"-object and then to JSON string. My problem now changes to "How to convert VARIANT to jsoncpp-value". In other words the actual conversion is not done automatically, right? I still have to manually say that this is an array and this is a boolean, etc.